# Sorting the records based on the field value in ascending order

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have below detail records, inside detail record multiple segments are repeating. based on the customer number Detail needs to be sort in ascending order. In the below XML 2 detail records are there, each detail record contains multiple segments. first detail record is related customerno 120 and second is customerno 99. output should be in ascending order. first one should be 99 and second should be 120.
Please help me with the below requirement.

**Input xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:Invoice
xmlns:ns0="urn:file.com:integration:api">
<Header_00>
    <Type>00</Type>
    <Filler/>
    <Name>EDG</Name>
</Header_00>
<Detail>
    <ID>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Customerno>120</Customerno>
        <BillingDate>20200201</BillingDate>
        <FromDate>00000000</FromDate>
    </ID>
    <Totals>
        <Type>9</Type>
        <Customerno>120</Customerno>
        <Due>135</Due>
    </Totals>
    <Totals_1>
        <Type>8</Type>
        <Customerno>120</Customerno>
        <Unit>E</Unit>
        <Due>00001</Due>
    </Totals_1>
    <Totals_1>
        <Type>8</Type>
        <Customerno>120</Customerno>
        <DistributionGroup/>
        <Unit>4</Unit>
        <Due>80</Due>
    </Totals_1>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <ID>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Customerno>99</Customerno>
        <BillingDate>20210201</BillingDate>
        <FromDate>00000000</FromDate>
    </ID>
    <Totals>
        <Type>9</Type>
        <Customerno>99</Customerno>
        <Due>789</Due>
    </Totals>
    <Totals_1>
        <Type>8</Type>
        <Customerno>99</Customerno>
        <Unit>4</Unit>
        <Due>0071</Due>
    </Totals_1>
</Detail>
<Trailer>
    <Type>90</Type>
    <Number>0000002</Number>
    <NumberOfRecords>2</NumberOfRecords>
</Trailer>
</ns0:Invoice>
```

**Output xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:Invoice xmlns:ns0="urn:file.com:integration:api">
  <Header_00>
  <Type>00</Type>
  <Filler/>
  <Name>EDG</Name>    
  </Header_00>
    <Detail>
       <ID>
     <Type>1</Type>
     <Customerno>99</Customerno>
     
     <BillingDate>20210201</BillingDate>
     <FromDate>00000000</FromDate>
    
  </ID>
  <Totals>
     <Type>9</Type>
     <Customerno>99</Customerno>
     <Due>789</Due>
     </Totals>
     <Totals_1>
     <Type>8</Type>
     <Customerno>99</Customerno>
      <Unit>4</Unit>
    <Due>0071</Due>
     </Totals_1>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
     <ID>
     <Type>1</Type>
     <Customerno>120</Customerno>
     <BillingDate>20200201</BillingDate>
     <FromDate>00000000</FromDate>
     </ID>
     <Totals>
     <Type>9</Type>
     <Customerno>120</Customerno>
     <Due>135</Due>
     </Totals>
      <Totals_1>
     <Type>8</Type>
     <Customerno>120</Customerno>
     
     <Unit>E</Unit>
     <Due>00001</Due>
     >
  </Totals_1>
  <Totals_1>
     <Type>8</Type>
     <Customerno>120</Customerno>
     <DistributionGroup/>
     <Unit>4</Unit>
     <Due>80</Due>
      </Totals_1>
     </Detail>
    <Trailer>
    <Type>90</Type>
  <Number>0000002</Number>
  <NumberOfRecords>2</NumberOfRecords>
   </Trailer>
   </ns0:Invoice>
```

**XSLT CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
 <xsl:sort select="Customerno" order ="ascending"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:copy>

 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So sort the `Detail` nodes by `ID/Customerno`. Why is this a problem?

Comment: sorting by Customerno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use:

```
<xsl:sort select="Customerno" order ="ascending"/>
```

because you want to sort the `Detail` nodes - and `Customerno` is not a child of `Detail`. Also, if you want to sort only the `Detail` nodes, then sort only the `Detail` nodes:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="urn:file.com:integration:api">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Invoice">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Header_00"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail">
            <xsl:sort select="ID/Customerno" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Trailer"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @michael.hor257k.. my issue got resolved